# WiX Light.exe outputs "LGHT0204 : ICE80: This 32BitComponent [component name] uses 64BitDirectory [directory name]" for every wxs component

Tags: wix, light

During the creation of an msi file with Light.exe (without Visual Studio), I got a warning for every wxs component in my project.
The errors looked like this:

```
C:\path\WXS.wxs(10) : error LGHT0204 : ICE80: This 32BitComponent [component name] uses 64BitDirectory [directory name]
```

As far as I could tell, there were no 32 bit components among the files and Platform='x64' was set in the base wxs file.

Tried drinking coffe and crying to very little effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the recommendation of:
https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/xsd/wix/package/

The description of the package suggested the usage of the "-arch" switch directly with light.exe instead of specifying it with the Platform attribute.

Comment: And I can only accept my own answer in 2 days as a solution for some reason...

Comment: FYI- WiX 4 preview 1 just dropped and 32bit / 64bit is way easier.